# JOIN, GROUP BY, SUM Issue Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, inner-join, where-clause

Assuming I have this table

```
tableA
ID       value 
1          5
1          5
3          10
2          4 
2          2
1          2

tableB
ID        Name       
1         apple      
2         carrot      
3         banana
```

If the expected max value of apple is 10, carrot is 5, and banana is 15 the output table would be

```
table output
ID     Name       value
1      apple      12
2      carrot     6
```

what SQL statement I need to solve this?

what I have done so far:

```
SELECT a,ID, b.name , sum(a.valueSUM) AS value FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN tableB b 
ON a.id = b.id 
GROUP BY id
```

what options i need on the WHERE clause to pull this off?

Comment: Your `group by` usage is invalid SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Which logic to get your output result? For eg with `ID = 1`, how to get `name = 'banana'` and `value = 10` from your `tableA` and `tableB`?

Comment: question updated. Its mysql

Comment: hi Pham, well I added all the values for 1, then we need to check if the carrot exceeds max value. If it does, add the result for the query. updated the table because of typo

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid, will raise an error on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), and return an unpredictable result on older MySQL versions. The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: Ok, so bananas are SUM() = 10, carrots = 6 and apples = 12. So bananas didn't go over threshold of 15, while apples and carrots did so they are in the result. Why tho carrots have actual sum, while apples are showing threshold? Is this mistake in example result or some unexplained part of calculations?

Comment: ohh sorry I missed the last part of table A, I was thinking of removing it on the first post but a train of thought appears and forgot to remove it. Thanks. Updated the question.

Comment: noted jarlh. I was just following the code I've read about Group By, it looks like i have a different understanding of it.

Comment: So the logic is clear. Then another problem is that do you have only `apple, carrot, banana` and 3 threshold as input? Or this is only sample data and in real case, it may be dynamic (n items, n thresholds....) ?

Comment: this is a sample data in a real case. I only need 3 thresholds as input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner subquery groups them normally and then the main query is what deals with limiting the results.

```
SELECT * FROM 
     (select 
      b.id,
      b.name as name, 
      SUM(a.value) as the_sum
      from tableA a inner join tableB b 
      on a.Id = b.id 
      group by b.name, b.id
     ) y
where (name = 'apple' and the_sum >= 10) OR
  (name = 'banana' and the_sum >= 15) OR
  (name = 'carrot' and the_sum >= 5)
```

It seems your sample data has changed, please try this. I thought the ID doesnt have to follow tableA/tableB's id and the id is auto-generated as per the results.

Would be nice if you have another table that sets the threshold per name

Comment: Hi, is this mysql? this is my first time to see it like that.

Comment: Gives expected result, just need to remove those hashes from table names.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński oh yep sorry I was testing this on my computer and doesnt want the bother of dropping the tables manually. Updated the code.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming threshold can be specified in tableB (makes sense):

```
SELECT a.ID, b.name, sum(a.value) AS value
FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN tableB b 
ON a.id = b.id 
GROUP BY a.ID, b.name, b.Threshold
HAVING sum(a.value) > b.Threshold;
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/ICOQF10295

Comment: unfortunately, the treshold cant be specified in tableB. But yeah it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TableB.id, TableB.Name, MAX(TableA.value) AS Value
FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableB ON
TableA.id = TableB.id
GROUP BY TableB.id, TableB.Name
```

Instead of SUM, use MAX aggregate function

Answer (score 0):

This works in SQL Server

```
--Existing tables
create table #tableA (ID int, value int)
create table #tableB (ID int, Name varchar(30))


insert into #tableA
select 1 , 5 union all  
select 1 , 5 union all  
select 3 , 10 union all  
select 2 , 4 union all  
select 2 , 2 union all  
select 1 , 2

insert into #tableB    
select 1 , 'apple' union all  
select 2 , 'carrot' union all 
select 3 , 'banana'   

--Create new temporary table @tableC

create table #tableC (ID int, MAXvalue int)


insert into #tableC    
select 1 , 10 union all  
select 2 , 5  union all  
select 3 , 15 


select c.ID,b.Name, a.value from #tableC c
inner join #tableB b on b.ID = c.ID
inner join (
    select ID,SUM(value) as value from #tableA
    group by ID
) a on a.ID = c.ID
where a.value >= c.MAXvalue

drop table #tableA
drop table #tableB
drop table #tableC
```